# Issue with Hibernate's hbm2ddl creating a unique index unduly

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, hbm2ddl, unique-index

I am encountering a serious issue with Hibernate's hbm2ddl and MySQL: **Hibernate systematically creates a unique index for the one  of the fields of my OneToMany associations** as follows:

[image: screen capture]

Notice the **UQ** box is checked for the `day_to_time_slots` field which does not make any sense...

Here is the relationship in the `Advertisement` entity:

```
@OneToMany
private List<DayToTimeSlot> dayToTimeSlots;
```

Here is the `DayToTimeSlot` entity:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooEquals
@RooJpaEntity
@Entity
public class DayToTimeSlot {

    @NotNull(groups = { Default.class, Validation.AdvertisementCreation.class })
    @Enumerated
    private Day day;

    @NotNull(groups = { Default.class, Validation.AdvertisementCreation.class })
    @Enumerated
    private TimeSlot timeSlot;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That makes perfectly sense - it works exactly as it should work. Table `advertisement_day_to_time_slots` is a join table between `Advertisement` and `DayToTimeSlot` entities. Relation between these entities is built with join table because association is unidirectional one-to-many.

**This join table do have unique constraint in day_to_time_slot column, because each DayToTimeSlot can be connected only to the one Advertisement entitity.** Inverse of OneToMany is ManyToOne. One Advertisement can be connected to many DayToTimeSlot entities, but one DayToTimeSlot is associated only with one Advertisement. If such a limitation is not preferred, [@ManyToMany](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html) association should be used instead of OneToMany.

Comment: Mikko: you're right of course. Thanks a lot. Sorry for this mistake on my part...